# Counting Strikes from Dynamic Probing: Reliable Impulse Detection

Tags: classification, time-series, autoencoder

Im looking for general guidance and advice to solve a specific application problem.

Let me explain the contect briefly: In geotechnics, there is a method called "dynamic probing" to examine the ground and soil before conducting any concstruction activities. Usually a geologist will conduct the "dynamic probing" process and will produce the resulting diagram, which is the base for the following work. The process is described here (unfortunately only in german, but there is a video showing the process): https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammsondierung

Basically you use a big weight (the so called hammer (approx 100 pound), to drive a metal rod into the ground and count how many strikes per unit of enty depth is required. The issue here is, that 1. you need to count the strikes in your head and 2. strike number in the range of 100 or so ar possible. This very cumbersome.

So we have the task to develop a counter for such machines, which counts the strikes automatically. The only constraint is, that we are not allowed to alter or mount anything on the hammer or the machine itself. This means we cannot use a inductive or some other sensor on the machine itself. So we have found two other options for getting a signal of these strikes:

1. A microphone, which measures the sound of the hammer hitting the anvill
2. An accelerometer placed on the ground, detecting vibration from the strikes transfered over the ground

Now we need a method to recocnize valid strike impulses either in the sound signal or the accelerometer signal. The problem is tough to tackle with classic aproaches as there ar so many unknows:

- The heigt und duration of the impulse is unclear so aproaches with thresholds do not work well
- The time between the impulses is quite constant (aprox 800ms apart)
- Height of background noise is unclear
- Other disturbances are present sometimes (other construction equipment) producing noise
- Distinct Features of the impulse are very hard to quantify

Here is an example of a good signal, with easily detectable impulses:
[image]

Here is an example of a very weak signal, with bad SNR:
[image]

Now the question:
Which process for analyzing the 1D-Vector from the accelerometer or the microphone would you choose, for a relaible detection of valid strike impulses?

Autoencoders or something in this direction? I would greatly apreciate any advice and a general direction in where to do further research.

Any input would be greatly apreciated, as the machine learning topic is very new for me and Im a little lost on where to start.

Thanks alot
Best Regards